# Entity object for newly added objects instead of dynamic proxy Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

i have a repository which have add and search methods

```
   public virtual void Add(T obj)
    {
        _table.Attach(obj);
        _table.Add(obj);
    }


     public virtual IEnumerable<T> Search(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _db.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }
```

then on my controller after i add a new object  of customer note using add method and save changes i use search to retrieve the notes based on customer Id and i get a list as the picture below and the newly added object is type poco class and all virtual navigation properties are not loaded i made a workaround by using include, is there explanation why EF do this

[Quick watch List for retrieved list from search method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kijrs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF create proxies only for entity instances it creates - either implicitly when materializing a query or explicitly when you use `DbSet.Create` methods. Any method which receives user provided object instance (like `Add`, `Remove`, `Attach`, `Entry` etc.) does not modify (wrap with proxy) the passed object.

Why? Because doing so will make many methods throwing *"The instance of entity type X cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked"* due to the fact that EF uses *reference equality* for tracking entity instances.

If you attach, add etc. plain (non proxied) object instances, they'll remain this way for the lifetime of the context or until explicitly detached.

Comment: so what i did of including the objects i need is not a workaround , right?

Comment: or there are a best practice from what i did? thanks Ivan

Comment: I don't think there are better practices, especially when working with disconnected entities received from somewhere else.